# How to simulate pressing the F4 key in Swift?

Tags: xcode

I have a **WkWebView** browser in my application, is it possible to send an imitation of pressing the **F4** button directly to it directly or in some other way?

In a similar application only on *Android*, I do this using the `dispatchKeyEvent()` method, and how can this be done in **Swift**?

*In practice, it should look like this:* the user launches the application, makes a long tap on the screen and an imitation of pressing the **F4** button is triggered.

It remains for me to do an imitation of pressing the **F4** key.

Comment: Please specify the platform. Also, why is `F4` important? I mean what is the action you intend to perform?

Comment: @Alladinian, XCode. 
I need to press the F4 button, and the action will take place from the side of JS. I tried this: webView.evaluateJavaScript("keyboardEvent[initMethod](\"keydown\",true,true,window,false,false,false,false,115,0);document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);"), but not successful.